# pandas json_normalize returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, twitter

I am trying to normalise fetched Twitter json data. The data is being fetched from the twitter API but while normalizing it the dataframe returns empty. I printed the incoming data so I am sure that the data is been fetched.
My code:

```
    def API_scrap(self, name_list, count_num,auth):
        api = tweepy.API(auth) 
        fail_list = []
        user_dfs = {}
        count = 0
        for name in name_list:
            if count % 300 == 0:
                print(count)
            count += 1
            try:
                data = api.user_timeline(name, count=count_num, tweet_mode='extended')
                user_dfs[name] = pd.DataFrame()
                for i in range(len(data)):
                    jdata = pd.json_normalize(data[i]._json)
                    user_dfs[name] = user_dfs[name].append(jdata, ignore_index=True)
            except:
                fail_list.append(name)
                continue
        print(user_dfs) 
        return user_dfs, fail_list
```

Output which I am getting is :

```
0
{871036856434950144: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 2537962288: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [], 2436012276: Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
```

It would be great if someone can help me out here.

Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Upgraded pandas to the latest version

Comment: Is this an answer that solved your problem? Or an update to your question?

Comment: Answer to the question

Comment: If this is a bug in a specific version, then you could at least state that and point to some official resource showing it. As it stands now, the answer doesn't even state which of the methods in your code changes it's behavior depending on the version.

Comment: @majidhajibaba This is actually an answer to the question. If you think it is not a *good* one - downvote it, don't vote to delete something that tries, however badly, to answer the question. Please read [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/6045800)